# Oracle result skips row if field exceeds column dimensions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have query that returns amplifying information about a subject. To fit on a 4:3 display monitor, I have limited the linesize to 138, and the amplify field has a character limit of 30. Frequently, I get long comments ~90-120 characters long.

It is fine that it spills over into the next row, but it seems to add a carriage return that causes a blank line to be between it and the next result. This is making it hard visually to keep like groups together, is there a way to make it not skip that extra line?

Comment: You're talking about SQL\*Plus here?

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL*Plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL*Plus, you can do:

```
set recsep off
```

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG097):

> RECSEP tells SQL*Plus where to make the record separation.
>
> For example, if you set RECSEP to WRAPPED, SQL*Plus prints a record separator only after wrapped lines. If you set RECSEP to EACH, SQL*Plus prints a record separator following every row. If you set RECSEP to OFF, SQL*Plus does not print a record separator.

You're seeing the default `wrapped` behaviour, because your long line is being wrapped. Setting it to `off` stops the extra line being added.

Comment: Perfect, I had no idea where to even go find that. Thank you!